# Binding Command inside DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: silverlight, binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have View(XAML included) attached to my ViewModel with commands. I need to invoke command when Button on DataGrid's row clicked. I'm using behaviors for this (regular commanding have same issue). When I click button on DataGrid - my command does not get fired.

To illustrate issue - I placed ListBox on a bottom with EXACT same binding stuff - and yes, command works. So, it's something with DataGrid/DataGridTemplateColumn

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Cancel" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Cancel" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="1">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Select">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Button>  
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DeviceId}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Device" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Serial Number" Width="Auto" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastActivityOn}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Last Activity" Width="Auto" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClientVersion}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Client Version" Width="Auto" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OSVersion}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="OS Version" Width="Auto" />
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

            </sdk:DataGrid>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceId}"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Content="Select">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Why are you using an EventTrigger instead of using the Command property of the button?

Comment: @Jehof Using command presents same problem. I'm using event trigger for consistency throughout application

Comment: Hi @katit, did you forget to award me the bonus points? ;)

Comment: @Xin No, I didn't, it requires 12hr wait :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am pretty sure inside a `DataGrid`, you still need the [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) to make bindings working. The ElementName binding doesn't work (yes, it is working for `ListBox` templates, but not `DataGrid`, this is because DataGridTemplateColumn is not in the visual tree), even in Silverlight 4.

**UPDATE**

In Silverlight 5, `DataContextProxy` is not needed in a `DataGrid` thanks to the support of Ancestor binding.

**Example**

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}}" />
```

Comment: The default RelativeSourceMode value is platform-specific, so you should also set it, like <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is this line

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

cause in your XAML is no element defined with name Control (aka. x:Name="Control").

You should change **ElementName=Control** to **ElementName=LayoutRoot** if the command is defined on the DataContext that is bound to LayoutRoot.

I don´t know why this works in the ListBox.

Comment: I have x:Name = Control on my user control. And it works for ListBox